# How to access (In)Private Browsing/Incognito Mode in Metro IE/Firefox/Chrome?

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, windows-8, internet-explorer, private-browsing

As the title says, what is the easiest/quickest way to enter Private Browsing mode in the Metro/Modern UI versions of the browsers listed?

Answer (score 2):

Right Click on the IE screen, Click the 'Tab tools' button (the three little dots) and choose "New InPractice tab"

Answer (score 2):

In the Modern UI version of Chrome, you can just click Menu, New Incognito Window, as usual.

[image]

You can switch between the incognito session and the existing session using a new button in the corner:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

PowerShell method:

```
$IEPath = (Get-ItemProperty -LiteralPath 'HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\IEXPLORE.EXE' -ErrorAction Stop).'(default)' 
$ShortcutFileName = (Get-Item $IEPath).Basename 
$ShortcutFile = "$env:Public\Desktop\$ShortcutFileName InPrivate.lnk" 
$WScriptShell = New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell 
$Shortcut = $WScriptShell.CreateShortcut($ShortcutFile) 
$Shortcut.TargetPath = $IEPath 
$Shortcut.Arguments = "-private" 
$Shortcut.IconLocation = $IEPath 
$Shortcut.Save()
```

More details [How to create a shortcut to start IE in private mode by PowerShell](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/How-to-create-a-shortcut-5ea4e42b)